# Is there any difference between "changing mind on something" and "changing mind about something"

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between "changing mind on something" and "changing mind about something"? Are these two expressions interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a difference.  For example, these two sentences mean the same thing to me:

- After thinking hard, I've changed my mind about applying for that job.
- After thinking hard, I've changed my mind on applying for that job.

I think that technically, "about" *could* be considered more correct.  For example, [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+mind) uses this as an example for the idiom "change your mind": "After the interview I completely changed my mind about her abilities."